# Why I cant click on a ListView Item when I added a checkbox next to it in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a small listview which displays numbers and next to it  I added a checkbox but, then its not clickable why? Do I have to do something to the adapter?

The listview item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtPlayerItemNo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_player"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IN"
        android:id="@+id/chk_ingame"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</TableRow>
```

And the ListView XML

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/ListPlayerNumbers"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="6.20"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:scrollingCache="true" />
```

Comment: I recommend using RecyclerView, it is much faster in theory and you can add different listeners right inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `checkbox.setFocusable(false)` in your `getView()` method. This will allow your list item to get click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to create your own adapter that can handling the checking/unchecking of the box. Here is an example that handles check boxes and tracks which are clicked. You use it like this:

```
                listMenuItems.setAdapter(null);                         
                sa = new MenuListCustomAdapter(appContext, items, R.layout.listmenuitemlayout,  from, to);                             
                listMenuItems.setAdapter(sa);


//Custom listview adapter than handles complex items in the list.
private class MenuListCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
{

     private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

     public MenuListCustomAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
     {
        super(context, objects, resource, from, to);             

        try
        {          
             for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
             {
                 myChecked.put(i, false);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e( clsGlobals.AppName, "Error in MenuActivity MenuListCustomAdapter: " + e.toString());             
        }
     }

     // handles the user checking items in the list.
     public void toggleChecked(int position)
     {
         try
         {
             int calValue = targetCals;

             if(myChecked.get(position))
             {
                 myChecked.put(position, false);
                 caloriesSelected = caloriesSelected - Integer.parseInt(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Calories").toString());
                 carbsSelected = carbsSelected - Integer.parseInt(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Carbohydrates").toString());                   
             }
             else
             {
                 myChecked.put(position, true);
                 caloriesSelected = caloriesSelected + Integer.parseInt(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Calories").toString());              
                 carbsSelected = carbsSelected + Integer.parseInt(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Carbohydrates").toString());  
             }

             calValue = calValue - caloriesSelected;
             txtMsg.setText("Target Cals: " + targetCals + "\r\nCals. remaining: " + calValue + "\r\nSelected carbs: " + carbsSelected);

             if (calValue < 0)
             {
                 txtMsg.setTextColor(txtBoxRed);
             }
             else
             {
                 txtMsg.setTextColor(txtBoxBlack);
             }

             notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e( clsGlobals.AppName, "Error in MenuActivity toggleChecked: " + e.toString());             
            }            
     }


     public List<HashMap<String, String>> getCheckedItems()
     {
         List<HashMap<String, String>> checkedItems =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         for(int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++)
         {
             if (myChecked.get(i))
             {
                 (checkedItems).add(locatedMenuItems.get(i));
             }
         }

         return checkedItems;
     }

     //Fills the items in the view. Gets called once per item being inserted in the list.
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
         View row = null;

         try
         {            
             row = convertView;

             if(row==null)
             {
                 LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                 row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listmenuitemlayout, parent, false);  
             }

             CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lstDesc);
             checkedTextView.setText(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("MenuItemDesc").toString());

            // TextView textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lstName);
            // textView.setText(locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("MenuItemName").toString());

             TextView tvAttribs = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lstAttribs);

             String temp = " Cals: " + locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Calories").toString() + ", Carbs: " + locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Carbohydrates").toString();
             temp+= ", Sodium: " + locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Sodium").toString();
             temp+= ", Fat: " + locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Fat").toString();
             temp+= ", Protein: " + locatedMenuItems.get(position).get("Protein").toString();            

             tvAttribs.setText(temp);            

             Boolean checked = myChecked.get(position);

             if (checked != null)
             {
                 checkedTextView.setChecked(checked);
             }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e( clsGlobals.AppName, "Error in MenuActivity toggleChecked: " + e.toString());             
            }

         return row;
     }

}
```